# Python3 - sorting a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I don't understand why 1 and 5 are printed three times.
(I know I could use the `list.sort()` method.)

```
lst = [4,5,5,1,6,1]
copy = lst.copy()
sort = []
for i in range(len(lst)):
    min_ = min(copy)
    for k in copy:
        if k == min_:
            sort.append(min_)
    copy.remove(min_)
print(sort)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list.remove()` removes the *first* occurrence of the value, not all such values. As a result you'll first add both `1` values to `sort`, remove one of the two `1` values, then add the remaining `1` value to `sort` again:

```
>>> lst = [4,5,5,1,6,1]
>>> copy = lst.copy()
>>> sort = []
>>> min_ = min(copy)
>>> min_
1
>>> for k in copy:
...     if k == min_:
...         sort.append(min_)
... 
>>> sort
[1, 1]
>>> copy.remove(min_)
>>> copy
[4, 5, 5, 6, 1]
>>> min_ = min(copy)
>>> min_
1
>>> for k in copy:
...     if k == min_:
...         sort.append(min_)
... 
>>> sort
[1, 1, 1]
```

You could use a list comprehension to remove all values, by essentially creating a new copy that excludes the value to remove by filtering:

```
copy = [v for v in copy if v != min_]
```

This is not very efficient, of course.

Note that the next problem you'll run into is that you'll have emptied out `copy` before you have completed all `range(len(lst))` iterations. You could replace that loop with a `while copy:` loop instead.

Alternatively, you could just add the *first* match of the `min_` value to `sort`:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    min_ = min(copy)
    for k in copy:
        if k == min_:
            sort.append(min_)
            break
    copy.remove(min_)
```

The `break` ends the `for` loop early. Of course, you don't even have to loop to find that minimum value, that is what the `min()` call *already did*, so you can drop it altogether:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    min_ = min(copy)
    sort.append(min_)
    copy.remove(min_)
```